# Install Mac drivers on Linux

Tags: mac, drivers, linux-mint

I have been able to install Linux Mint onto my 2015 MacBook Pro.

I want to know this because I cannot right click at the moment as well as scrolling up and down webpages/terminal etc. Also it would be good to be able to use the built in Wi-Fi card instead of a wireless dongle.

Also would would I have to install/change to use the display/keyboard light settings as well as the media and sound controls.

Also are there ant other drivers that I should install on my Mac running Linux to make it run smoother? If so could you tell me how to install them too please?

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. Are you asking if you can install OSX drivers in Linux Mint? If so, the answer is no. These are entirely different operating systems; the drivers are not compatible.

Comment: @ChrisInEdmonton What I want to do is install software that allows me to use the ForceTouch trackpad in Linux (right now I can only single click, I would like to be able to right click, scroll with 2 fingers etc.) I would also like to be able to use the media player keys (F7-F12) (Which Ive been able to do with shortcuts) however I cannot use the keyboard and screen brightness keys (F1-F1,F5-F6). How would I enable compatibility for the hardware? Would it be drivers (this is what I'm asking) I also want to know how to use the built-in Network Card etc.